# TextField text needs to mirror text from another ViewController’s TextField input

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield

My Current Setup

**ViewController3**:

This ViewController has 18 `TextFields` stacked vertically. This is the “settings” screen where the user can add their default text (single words, comments or sentences). This view also has a `save` button to save using `UserDefaults`, which is working fine.

To access this view (settings screen) the user taps the `settings` button located on the main view (`ViewController1`) via a show segues. Once all editing done to the default texts (usually a once off and reused again and again), they tap the `save` button and then tap `Done` button to return to `ViewController1`.

**ViewContoller2**:

This ViewController has matching 18 TextFields (again stacked vertically), but each with a selection switch. If switch is active, means that `TextField` is selected. Out of the 18 `TextFields` which are stacked vertically, the user can select any given number of them.

The selected ones are then populated as a selected list of texts in the mail body of an email being sent from a `Send Email` button back on `ViewController1`.

**ViewController1**:

This is the main view of the app where the app will send off the email after entering desired text into a number of `TextFields` and it included the `TextView` that has the selected list of texts from `ViewController2`

**Note:** All transitions between ViewControllers are via show segues.

> Question 1:
>
> What code or how to write the code to enable the TextFields in ViewController2 to auto populate (copy or mirror) the text that has been entered it the TextFields in ViewController3?
>
> Question 2:
>
> How do get the selected TextFields from ViewController2 to show up in the body of the email as a list of items but vertically stacked on their individual lines?

Comment: **Question 1:** Use NSNotificationCenter , **Question 2:** Append all texts into single string with new line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, let me see if I undestood.

- VC3 is the settings view where you "register" the texts to be used at some point.
- VC2 is the view that you select which texts you want to use/send/whatever
- VC1 is the main screen, where you are displaying the texts you chose above

If you are using segues, I believe that your VC2 is not instanced when you are registering or changing data on the VC3. So, NotificationCenter is not an option like @dahiya_boy told.

If you are saving all the data on UserDefaults, can't you just load this data and apply on each TextField on VC2 when the user open the VC2 screen (probably on `viewDidLoad` )

Your second question... whats the problem?

If the problem is passing data between the VC2 and VC1, you can use NotificationCenter, or delegate.

If the problem is how to show it as a stack, so you can pass it as an array from VC2 to VC1 and appending everything using `joined(separator:)` and passing `\n` as the separator. (symbol for newline)

Comment: Thanks @FormingaNinga, ill have a crack at it, really appreciate your help